# Does EF Core 3.1 support use of SQL Views inside of code-first DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I currently have an ASP.NET Core project using EF 3.1. I would like to use Code-First to manually build most of my entities, but there is also a linked server I need to incorporate data from as well. I need to figure out how to create an entity model that is the result of this view (that includes a left join from a code-first table I have already migrated). During my research thus far, it seems that since EF3 there is support for views inside of Scaffold-DbContext, but my concern is I would only want to scaffold this single view, but still access everything inside the same DbContext I am already using. I don't want to hack things together, so please let me know how you would accomplish such a task in your project. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was able to figure this out after all. The steps I did are as follows, but please correct me if you know a better or more accepted way.

1. Selected the SQL view into a new table so I could generate a create script off of it.
2. Copied the create script into the class creation tool over at https://codverter.com/src/sqltoclass so didn't have to manually convert 20+ columns and types to class properties.
3. Copied the generated properties into a new model class named after the SQL view
4. Added a new DbQuery under my existing DbSets in my DbContext class. (It does seem like DBQuery is deprecated, but I don't see another way around using it currently) and named it the same as my SQL view.
5. Scaffolded a new controller off the SQL views model class and navigated to the generated index page to verify data could be seen. (it worked!)

Let me know if you have any better ideas on how I came to this solution!